# Cell interiour colour formatting

Tags: vba

I have a workbook with various worksheets. They are all connected; they are a copy of each other.

I need so that when I edit the first worksheet (edit in the sense of formatting) all the other worksheets are edited.

I know how to use the copy cell formula (for what is inside the cell), but I don't know how to create a formula where the formatting is copied (I need to copy if the original cell is Bold or the cell colour or the cell boarders).

Like if cell A1 is red, I need that cell A3 is also red (this needs to be automatic).

Also, I need to come up with a formula that if the cell colour is red then a formula is applied. Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing (automatically changing the formatting of a cell when the formatting of another cell changes) is not possible. Excel does not fire any events when a cell's formatting changes. The best you could do would be to copy formatting when a cell's value changes. So, for example, if a user changes the font color to red for cell A3, and then adds a border to cell B7, nothing would happen. But when the user changes the value of cell C1 from 7 to "John", then you could use the worksheet change event to check the formatting of cells and copy any formatting over to the appropriate cells. A word of warning though: limit the range of cells you loop through for this, or it will be a horrendously slow process!